# How do I compute $\displaystyle \frac{d^2t}{d\lambda^2} - \frac{2}{t}\left(\frac{dt}{d\lambda}\right)^2=0.$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

can anyone help me on how to compute the following differential equation?

$$\displaystyle \frac{d^2t}{d\lambda^2} - \frac{2}{t}\left(\frac{dt}{d\lambda}\right)^2=0.$$

Comment: You can start with an ansatz as to the form of $t(\lambda)$; there are several natural ones that come to mind, and one at least that produces a specific solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have either $t'(λ)=0$ or you can divide to
$$
\frac{t''(λ)}{t'(λ)}-2\frac{t'(λ)}{t(λ)}=0
$$
This is now fully integrable and results in
$$
t'(λ)=Ct(λ)^2,
$$
which is separable and easy to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p=\frac{dt}{d\lambda}$, then $\frac{d^2t}{d\lambda^2}=\frac{dp}{d\lambda}=\frac{dp}{dt}\frac{dt}{d\lambda}=\frac{dp}{dt}p$

Now,

$\frac{dp}{dt}p-\frac{2}{t}p^2=p(\frac{dp}{dt}-\frac{2}{t}p)=0$

One solution is $p=0$ which gives $t=c$

The other solution is $\frac{dp}{dt}-\frac{2}{t}p=0$ which gives

$\frac{dp}{p}-\frac{2dt}{t}=0$

$ln\frac{p}{t^2}=c_1$

$\frac{p}{t^2}=c_1$

$\frac{dt}{t^2}=c_1d\lambda$

$\frac{-1}{t}=c_1\lambda+c_2$

Hence, $t=\frac{1}{c_1\lambda+c_2}$ and $t=c$ are solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Let $dt/d\lambda=v$. Then notice the useful identity $\frac{dv}{d\lambda}\cdot dt=vdv=\frac{d^2 t}{d\lambda^2}$. Hence, using this to replace $d^2 t/d\lambda^2$, we have $vdv=2v^2 dt/t$. One solution here is $v=dt/d\lambda=0$ (so just constant $t$), but assuming it isn't, then $dv/v=2dt/t$. Integrating should then give $\log v=2\log t+c$, or, $v=ct^2=dt/d\lambda$. Then $cd\lambda=t^{-2}dt$, which integrates to $c_1\lambda+c_2=-1/t$, or, $t=-1/(c_1\lambda+c_2)$. I guess that can be cleaned up to simply $t=\frac{c_1}{\lambda+c_2}$.